# Let $T$ be a strongly cartesian monad on a presheaf category $\hat C$. Then is $\hat C$ comonadic over $\operatorname{Alg} T$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

$\DeclareMathOperator\Alg{Alg}\newcommand{\Set}{\mathit{Set}}\newcommand{\Set}{\mathit{Set}}\newcommand{\Ab}{\mathit{Ab}}$Let $C$ be a small category, and let $T$ be a [strongly cartesian monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/parametric%20right%20adjoint) on the presheaf category $\hat C$. Let $\Alg(T)$ be the category of algebras for $T$. Then the adjunction between $F : \hat C \rightleftarrows \Alg(T) : U$ is (by definition) monadic. Is it also comonadic? That is, I'm asking the following

**Question 1:** In the above situation, does the "free $T$-algebra" functor $F : \hat C \to \Alg(T)$ exhibit $\hat C$ as the category of coalgebras for the induced comonad $FU$ on $\Alg(T)$?

When $T$ is the free category monad on the category of directed graphs, the answer is *yes*. That is, directed graphs are comonadic over categories. Likewise (but slightly outside the scope of the above question because the monad is not strongly cartesian), the free abelian group functor $\Set \to \Ab$ is comonadic.

**Question 2:** Supposing the answer to Question 1 is yes, and I want to get greedy, is there a larger "nice" class of monads for which the canonical monadic adjunction is also comonadic?

I just realized that the definition I'm using is kind of buried in the nlab article I linked to, so let me clarify that a monad is "strongly cartesian" for me if the underlying functor $T$ preserves connected limits, and the naturality squares for the unit and multiplication are pullback squares.